# implementing the right permissions for move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, iis, upload, permissions

I am running a php / IIS 8 website.

I have followed the directions here:

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/implementing-uploadify/

My users are able to upload files onto my server.

However, when I call the function move_uploaded_file:

```
      $imagename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
      $source = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
      $target = "../ResLife/uploadimages/".$imagename;
      move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
```

nothing happens. it does not move the file.

what am i doing wrong? how can i set the proper permissions so that this function gets executed?

Comment: You need to ensure that the user that has been setup to run IIS has write permissions on the folder in question. Normally `iis_user` or `NETWORK_SERVICE` if I recall correctly.

Comment: @gavin thanks so much! i do have the right permissions to be able to upload. however i cannot figure out what the first couple of lines mean: $imagename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];  --- what is ;filedata??

Comment: Don't do this. using the user-provided `['name']` like that is opening your server to a total remote compromise, allowing a malicious user to scribble a file ANYWHERE on your server.

Comment: @MarcB thanks so much. .can you please explain to me exactly what that line does?

Comment: `['name']` is provided by the user, so imagine they hack an upload to say the filename is `../../../../../../etc/passwd`. not that this works as is, but gives you an idea of what COULD happen. you're basically giving users the opportunity to specify exactly WHERE on your server THEY want to write a file.

Comment: @MarcB thanks a lot. that's an eye opener! i did not know that. i will research how to make the change. how do i know what tmp_name is referring to?
\